# Python parsing (think its JSON)

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing, nested

Reformulated question:

Hi,

When I run this code:

```
import pageviewapi
views = pageviewapi.per_article('en.wikipedia', 'Samuel_John_Carter','20150701','20191201', access='all-access', agent='user', granularity='monthly')   
print(views)
print(type(views))
```

I get this result:

```
AttrDict({'items': [{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2015070100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 75}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2015080100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 64}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2015090100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 94}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2015100100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 90}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2015110100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 91}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2015120100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 73}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2016010100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 91}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2016020100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 88}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2016030100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 82}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2016040100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 95}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2016050100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 86}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2016060100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 76}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2016070100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 75}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2016080100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 81}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2016090100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 79}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2016100100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 173}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2016110100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 170}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2016120100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 84}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2017010100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 131}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2017020100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 76}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2017030100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 94}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2017040100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 234}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2017050100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 213}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2017060100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 286}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2017070100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 190}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2017080100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 186}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2017090100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 175}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2017100100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 212}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2017110100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 255}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2017120100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 231}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2018010100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 339}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2018020100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 257}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2018030100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 299}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2018040100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 254}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2018050100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 262}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2018060100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 242}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2018070100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 197}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2018080100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 187}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2018090100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 191}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2018100100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 223}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2018110100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 256}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2018120100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 211}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019010100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 255}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019020100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 244}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019030100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 257}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019040100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 230}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019050100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 234}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019060100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 199}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019070100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 224}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019080100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 207}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019090100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 255}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019100100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 265}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019110100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 330}]})

<class 'attrdict.dictionary.AttrDict'>
```

I'm a newbie white knuckling my way here.  Can anybody suggest a specific way to get all the timestamp:views datapoints from this messy output?  I'd love to know if this is a nested dictionary or json object.

Thanks so much for any help anybody would be able to offer!

---

*Original question:
Spinning my wheels here.  I'm trying to work with output from a Python script.  When I print the output, I get something like this (much more, of course).

```
AttrDict({'items': [{'project': 'fr.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019010100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 35}, {'project': 'fr.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019020100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 11}]})
AttrDict({'items': [{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Giovanni_Battista_Merano', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2015070100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 35}, {'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Giovanni_Battista_Merano', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2015080100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 35}]})
```

What I'm trying to do is parse the data by selectively building out lines.  If anybody can help me figure out how I could get all the datapoints for article, timestamp and views from this data (for example), I think I'd be golden.
I'm note even sure if this thing a JSON or a Python Dictionary (print(type()) returns "class 'attrdict.dictionary.AttrDict'".
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!**

---

Comment: What library is AttrDict coming from?

Comment: `attrdict` isn't part of Python's standard library. You're either using it directly or indirectly.

Comment: The bit inside the parenthesis is a valid python dictionary, although it may also be valid JSON

Comment: 1. pageviewapi.per_article is generating the mess of text, set to variable "views"
2. when I print(type(views)), I get <class 'attrdict.dictionary.AttrDict'>

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using the JSON library's loads() (or load()) function?

load()/loads() both convert JavaScript objects into nested dictionaries in Python. That's why it's so messy to print.

I'm not completely understanding what your problem is, but you should be able to interact with whatever load()/loads() returns by treating it as a dictionary.
Here is a link to the JSON library documentation (which I'm guessing you've already seen)[[1](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage)]

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Honestly, I'm a newbie trying not to drown.  The data is generated by asking for monthly wikipedia page view counts using pageviewapi.  I think it is acting as a wrapper for a REST API call and returning the result which I think is JSON.  Using the data provided, would you be able to suggest the exact code that would solve the sample challenge?  That would really help.

Comment: So I'm not sure which article is which in the snippet you have. I think I may be able to help you decipher what you're looking at though. Let's first look at dictionary formatting: say I make a dictionary `my_dict = {}`. Then, say I add the mapping `my_dict["france"] = "baguette"`. If I do `print(my_dict)`, the output will be `{'france': 'baguette'}`. Now say I have an entry mapping to a list, like `my_dict["france"] = ["baguette", "frog legs"]`. Then, when I do `print(my_dict)` the output will be `{'france': ['baguette', 'frog legs']`. Starting to look familiar yet? _continued_ _below_

Comment: Now, say I make a dictionary with an entry that maps to another dictionary: `new_dict["germany"] = my_dict`. Then, `print(new_dict)` has output `{'germany': {'france': ['baguette, 'frog legs']}}`. Lastly, let's try a dictionary with an entry that maps to a list of dictionaries: `new_dict["germany"] = [my_dict, my_dict]`. Now, `print(new_dict)` outputs `{'germany': [{'france': ['baguette, 'frog legs']}, {'france': ['baguette, 'frog legs']}]}`. This is what you have: dictionaries of lists of dictionaries. Does this make sense? Does that help you interpret your outputs?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a *good* way to do it, but it should work:

Assuming that `print(foo)` gives you one line of the example output you posted:

Trim down the output to the part within the parenthesis:

```
s = str(foo)
s = s[10:-1]
```

Make a string that is code to store it in a variable:

```
s = "d = " + s
```

Run that code

```
exec(s)
```

This will make the variable `d` the dictionary that foo represents.

Obviously, be careful when using `exec` and make sure that the input is not coming from something that could be malicious.

Comment: Sorry, still trying to make sense of answer.  Do you think it will allow me to get all four datapoint sets from this maybe JSON, maybe nested dictionary?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So it looks to me like `views` is a nested dictionary. The type says AttrDict, and while I don't know what that is, I'm guessing its interface is similar to Python's built-in dictionary. If you do `views["items"]`, that should give you a list of dictionaries, which are all of the general form `{'project': 'en.wikipedia', 'article': 'Samuel_John_Carter', 'granularity': 'monthly', 'timestamp': '2019110100', 'access': 'all-access', 'agent': 'user', 'views': 330}`. See my comment to my other answer if you're confused on how to interpret that. Now, you will notice that each of the many dictionaries in this list have a `'views'` key and a `'timestamp'` key. You have to decide which mapped value you want (i.e. which dictionary you want) - I can't know which is the one you're interested in. If you want all of them, then iterate over this list and for each element `i` access those fields with `i["views"]` and `i["timestamp"]`. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice!

I decided to try something different, go directly to the Wikipedia Rest API.

Bellow is the code I used:

```
import requests
from csv import reader

opened_file = open("file to read")
read_file = reader(opened_file)
unique_pages = list(read_file)


write_file = open("file to write results", "w")


for row in unique_pages:    
    #first load in variables from file
    lang = row[0]
    page_title = row[1] 
    url = row[2]
    ulan_id = row[3]
    ulan_name = row[4]
    wsearch = row[0]+'.wikipedia'
    #next build URL
    pvurl = 'https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/metrics/pageviews/per-article/'+lang+'.wikipedia/all-access/user/'+page_title+'/monthly/20150701/20191201?'
    #next make request
    response = requests.get(pvurl)
    response_json  = response.json()
    #finally print results

    try:
        for i in response_json['items']: 
            _pvarticle = i['article']
            _pvproject = i['project']
            _pvtimestamp = i['timestamp']
            _views = i['views']
            print(_pvarticle,'|',_pvproject,'|',_pvtimestamp,'|',_views,'|',ulan_id,'|',ulan_name,'|',url,'|',lang)
            built_string = f"{_pvarticle}|{_pvproject}|{_pvtimestamp}|{_views}|{ulan_id}|{ulan_name}|{url}\n"
            write_file.write(built_string)
#            time.sleep(0.005)
    except:
            print(page_title,'|',lang+".wikipedia",'|','No Data','|','No Views','|',ulan_id,'|',ulan_name,'|',url,'|',lang)
            built_string = f"{page_title}|{lang}.wikipedia|No Data|No Data|{ulan_id}|{ulan_name}|{url}\n"
            write_file.write(built_string)
```

So, I'm just learning Python.  If anybody has suggestions to improve the code, please let me know!